# How to remove multiple items from a list?

Tags: clojure

I have a list [2 3 5] which I want to use to remove items from another list like [1 2 3 4 5], so that I get [1 4].

thanks

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
(let [a [1 2 3 4 5]
      b [2 3 5]]
  (remove (set b) a))
```

which returns `(1 4)`.

The `remove` function, by the way, takes a predicate and a collection, and returns a sequence of the elements that don't satisfy the predicate (a set, in this example).

Comment: ... which is O(n + m)

Comment: how does `(set)` function here as a predicate for `remove`? Can anyone explain it ? Doesn't need the predicate to return false for some items in coll?

Comment: A set is also a function that will return the value it is given if that value is in itself, or nil if it is not. If you use this function as a predicate then the value returned becomes true, or nil returned becomes false. This is because in Clojure nil is 'falsey'.

Answer (score 6):

```
user=> (use 'clojure.set)
nil
user=> (difference (set [1 2 3 4 5]) (set [2 3 5]))
#{1 4}
```

Reference:

- http://clojure.org/data_structures#toc22
- http://clojure.org/api#difference

Comment: A vector is not a set. The ordering of the vector is not preserved when you convert it to a set. 

If I understands the question correctly,
(difference (set [9 2 3 4 5]) (set [2 3 5]))
returns #{4 9} when it should return [9 4] and
(difference (set [1 1 2 3 4 5]) (set [2 3 5]))
should return [1 1 4] and not #{1 4}

If he wanted set semantics he probably would have used a set to begin with.

Comment: Thanks, Jonas. You're probably right about him not wanting set semantics.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this yourself with something like:

```
(def a [2 3 5])
(def b [1 2 3 4 5])

(defn seq-contains? 
  [coll target] (some #(= target %) coll))

(filter #(not (seq-contains? a %)) b)
; (3 4 5)
```

A version based on the [reducers](http://clojure.com/blog/2012/05/08/reducers-a-library-and-model-for-collection-processing.html) library could be:

```
(require '[clojure.core.reducers :as r])

(defn seq-contains? 
 [coll target] 
   (some #(= target %) coll))

(defn my-remove
"remove values from seq b that are present in seq a"
 [a b]
 (into [] (r/filter #(not (seq-contains? b %)) a)))

(my-remove [1 2 3 4 5] [2 3 5] )
; [1 4]
```

**EDIT** **Added seq-contains? code**

Comment: Hi Nicolas, I may be missing a point but, AFAIK contains? does not really check "content" rather it checks the index, check out this example;
(contains? [7 2 3 4 5 6] 6) ;;false, there is no element at index 6, although there is an element 6.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I totally forgot. Added the code for a seq-contains? function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take without using sets;

```
(defn my-diff-func [X Y] 
   (reduce #(remove (fn [x] (= x %2)) %1) X Y ))
```